Adjusting an Elbow in Publisher using VBA
I am working on a Macro in Publisher that adds an Elbow connector. I’ve got everything working except for one thing - after creating the Elbow, I need to adjust the position of the Yellow Diamond, so that the Connector has one Elbow, instead of two.
Here is the code that I use:
Sub subCreateArrowElbow() 
       
      Dim shpArrowElbow As Shape 
    
      Set shpArrowElbow = ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes.AddConnector _ 
        (Type:=msoConnectorElbow, _ 
        BeginX:=144, BeginY:=144, _ 
        EndX:=180, EndY:=72) 
      Call subFormatLineAndArrowhead(shpArrowElbow) 
    
    End Sub 
     
    Sub subFormatLineAndArrowhead(parmShape As Shape) 
    
      With parmShape 
        .Line.Weight = 2 
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192) 
        .Line.EndArrowheadLength = msoArrowheadLong 
        .Line.EndArrowheadWidth = msoArrowheadWide 
        .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadStealth 
      End With 
       
    End Sub

Here is the example, when I first call subCreateArrowElbow, it creates:

I can manually drag the Yellow Diamond, so that it appears line this:

But I cannot find anything in the Shape Object that manipulates this through VBA.
I tried to trap the action by creating the Elbow in a Word Document and then Record the Macro of my dragging the Yellow Diamond to match what I do in Publisher, however, the Macro only recorded my selecting the Object.
